Sentry config being overwritten
I have a react native application where I'm using @sentry/react-native(>3) package
I'm correctly initialising the sentry
Sentry.init({
  dsn: DSN,
  enabled: false
....
})

After introducing another package in the application let's say react-native-xyz I started to see this error when starting the application
"DSN is required. Use empty string or set enabled to false in SentryOptions to disable SDK."
After debugging I found out this file in sentry-java is throwing the error:
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/6259a9fdb9ec4b75001c93401e1d0b1c18541dfb/sentry/src/main/java/io/sentry/Sentry.java#L369
If you check the code present in this file there's an if condition present if sentry is not enabled return. which in our case should've have been run, but it is going into the else block
Upon removing the third party package this error is resolved and the app is running successfully
I checked with the package managers and they are using the Sentry in the package for event and crash logging
I think they have enabled their sentry in debug mode for every env, Is it possible that their sentry config is clashing with my config and the conditions are failing?
If yes then what would the possible fix for this
